# Проблема с настройкой редиректа в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Всем доброго времени суток!
У меня возникла следующая проблема - настроил htaccess переадресации с www версии сайт на версию без www - на главной странице сайта всё отлично работает. Но тут недавно проверил работает ли этот самый редирект на внутренних страницах сайта и обомлел... Получаемый url вообще не понятно от чего создаётся.
Вот пример:
http://alfa555.ru/catalog/vesovoy-chay-optom/
При попытке перейти на версию с www получается следующий адрес:
http://alfa555.ru/index.php/vesovoy-chay-optom/ и соответственно код 404.
В htaccess так же настроена переадресация с /index.php на корень сайта и некоторые другие редиректы. Но в чём проблема никак не могу понять.
Вот настройки mod_rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Перенаправляем на сайт с http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html|htm)\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Все запросы на сайт с www перенаправляем на сайт без www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.alfa555.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://alfa555.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Заранее всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Для понимания происходящего лучше сделать так: последовательно выпишите на листок все директивы rewrite, описав их словами со смыслом того, для чего они и что делают. Затем берете свой url `http://alfa555.ru/catalog/vesovoy-chay-optom/` и "прогоняете" его по всем правилам сверху вниз. Хинт №1: если какое-либо правило `RewriteRule` изменяет входной `url` (а он изменяет), а также содержит модификатор [L], то начинаете все сначала с уже измененным url-ом. И так до тех пор, пока ни один rewrite не изменит входной url.

Comment: Хинт №2: дебажить нужно в браузере с включенным инструментом разработчика и включенной опцией `Disable cache`. Зачем? Затем, чтобы не получать необъяснимое поведение rewrite. Модификаторы R=301 уже закэшились в вашем браузере и будут мешать правильному результату. Хинт №3 - никогда не используйте R=301, если железобетонно не уверены в свои правилах, лучше использовать просто R. Когда все отладите и появится уверенность, можно и 301 добавить. Так что пробуйте.